# Issue at binding service property to promise data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

The following issue is giving me headaches:

I have a service, which has a promise returning get method:

```
app.service('resultService',function($http,$q){
    return{

        currentDocument: {
            title: '',
            content: '',
            tags: ''
        },

        getDocument: function(title){

            var self = this;
            var defer = $q.defer();

            defer.resolve($http.get('./sys/core/getDocument.php',
              {params:{title: title}}).then(function(promise){
                return promise.data;
            }));

            return defer.promise;
        }
    }
});
```

This is working fine, and if I do a `console.dir(promise.data)` I can see a perfectly filled-in object:

```
    Object
content: "some good content"
tags: "goodTag"
title: "A nice title"
```

However, I would like to bind the promise data to a property of my service:

```
getDocument: function(title){

    var self = this;
    var defer = $q.defer();

    defer.resolve($http.get('./sys/core/getDocument.php',
       {params:{title: title}}).then(function(promise){
          self.currentDocument = promise.data;
          return promise.data;
    }));

    return defer.promise;
 }
```

Though, if I do so, `console.dir(promise.data)` will return:

```
Object
  content: undefined
  tags: undefined
  title: undefined
```

I have absolutely no idea what the heck is happening here. I also tried to bind the property in the function that takes the promise from `getDocument()`. Same result. To me, it looks like this is only happening when binding to a service property.

Comment: The service property does not get filled till the data is returned. Maybe you are trying to access data on the service property before the data has been returned.

Comment: is it possible to create a plunker to replicate?

Comment: @user, Promises don't work the way you think. The var you have named `promise`is not a Promise. It's hard to comment on what is going on without seeing where in the code your test statement `console.dir(promise.data)` sits.